# Electron.Tray.setImage does not update tray icon in some Icon Themes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, electron

I'm trying to figure out the problem for months. I have an electron app which has a tray icon. When there are notifications, the icon shows a the count in the tray. For this an icon in generated dynamically. Then the icon is set using `tray.setImage()` method. What is so weird is that this does not work on all icon themes.

1. OS: Linux
2. Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04
3. Desktop: Budgie

Tray icon gets updated in `Numix` icon and possibly some others too. But not on `Nordzy` and possibly many others.

I would want to understand why such behaviour. Could someone help please?